# Square root algorithm in modulo $n = pq$

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I've been stuck in this problem quite a bit.

I have to find an **efficient algorithm** wich, given:
$$
p = 4k+3\\
q = 4m+3\\
p,q \hspace{2mm} \text{odd primes}\\
a\in \mathbb{N}
$$

verifies if there exists some$\ b$ such that,
$$
b^2 \equiv a\pmod n,\quad n=pq,\quad b\in \mathbb{N}
$$

Something useful might be the following property, wich has already been proven:
$$
b^2 \equiv a\pmod n,\hspace{2mm} n=pq \Leftrightarrow c^2 \equiv a\pmod q  \wedge d^2 \equiv a\pmod p 
$$

but I'm not quite sure how to use that information.

All my approaches have been unsuccesful and I haven't been able to use the fact that $\ p$ and $\ q$ have a given form of$\ (4k + 3)$.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with *Euler's Criterion*? For that, the fact that the primes are of the form $4k+3$ is not relevant.

Comment: Maybe you can look up the Quadratic Reciprocity Law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If you use Euler's Criterion as suggested by André Nicolas and find that $a$ has square roots mod p, you know that $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Now set $r := a^{\frac{p+1}{4}} \pmod p$, and compute $r^2 \pmod p$. This uses the fact, that $p=4 k + 3$ and is effective **if** you have an effective modular exponentiation algorithm. If $a$ has square roots mod $p$ and $q$, then use the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Case_of_two_equations) to get square roots mod $n$.